# Return to top of Previous Page

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a button that takes me back to a previous view(of another view controller), however it takes me back to where i was last in that view. i want to always return to the top of that view, how ?

Comment: Could you post some code/maybe some more information? Do you use a `UINavigationController`?

Answer (score 2):

On the previous ViewController, override/implement viewWillAppear method.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   // you may change the position of the scrollview or you may re initialize desired views
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if your previous view is inherited from `UIScrollView` you should add that code for your specific view, I've included all main type of views, I'm not sure you will need all of it, but 
I don't know which one is your previous view, so you can choose the proper one.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero];
    [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:false];
    [textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the previous view write some code in viewWillAppear method which will refresh your view.
Because viewWillAppear method always get called whenever you visit a viewController.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

}
```